# MS Access 2007 adjacency list tree validate against circular reference

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I've implemented adjacency list tree in MS Access 2007. Upon insertion or update I want to validate against circular reference (like `a->b->c->a`). I've wrote a simple function that given table name and id of a tree node returns true if the path of references is finite and false if there is a loop.

Unfortunately, according to [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa191586(v=office.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa191586%28v=office.10%29.aspx):

> For field and record validation rules, the expression can't contain
>   user-defined functions, domain aggregate or aggregate functions, the
>   Eval function, or CurrentUser method, or references to forms, queries,
>   or tables. In addition, field validation rules can't contain
>   references to other fields. For records, expressions can include
>   references to fields in that table.

I'm limited to MS Access with Access database engine as backend. I know limitations of adjacency list trees model but I still prefer it.

What is the best way to validate those references?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put it in a validation rule. What you're trying to do is catch things on insert/update, but you should probably catch them before the insert or update.

To do that, make your own validation run your function in the BeforeUpdate event of the input controls, and Me.Undo and Msgbox (or otherwise inform the user of the error) if the function reveals that there will be a problem.

For example:

```
Private Sub Input_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Not inputIsValid() Then
        'input is not valid
        Me.Undo
        MsgBox "Input is not valid", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Invalid Input"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't try it atm, as I am not working with Access. I understand that you have to do this kind of validation in a form. So it can't prevent loops from being introduced via query, only prevent user from entering wrong data?

Comment: Yeah, if you wanted the former you'd have to work with a database that supports triggers, and set your validation code to run on a before insert trigger. As far as access with an access back-end, for any complicated validation like this you can only prevent the user from entering bad data prior to running the query.

Comment: Thanks. I give you +1 for the answer and +1 for the comment, but obviously can't mark this anwser as correct. Unfortunately your comment looks more like a correct answer :)